# Filtering based on the values in an R data frame

Tags: r, filter

This is a small sample of my data:

[image: data table]

The top row includes codes that denote different tree species (e.g. PJ = jack pine).  The numerical values represent counts of each species within survey plots.  Each case represents a stand that was assessed once by a forest manager (B), and then audited with a plot based survey by the regulating government agency (A).  I want to use chisq.test in R to determine the probability that the two samples were taken from the same population, essentially compare the results from source A to those from source B.  For each case, I want to convert the 0 values to NA where there is a 0 for both A and B sources.  Otherwise I am unnecessarily inflating the degrees of freedom for the test.  I am very new to R.

I want to do a chi squared test across many cases, and the entire data set contains up to 15 species.  In most cases there are 2-7 species to deal with.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Two ways of doing these types of operations: use `?reshape` to transform to a wide dataset and compare `PJ.A` and `PJ.B`. Or use `subset` for `source == 'A'` and 'B' respectively, create logicals: PJ0a and PJ0b and merge two-to-one  back to the original dataset on the merge-key `case`.

Comment: please use `dput()` or `dput(head())` instead of using a picture of your data.

Comment: ok, I'll try to do that in future

Comment: you can still do that. just edit your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `tidyverse` functions and try something like:

```
df %>%
group_by(Case) %>%
mutate( PJ = if_else(sum(PJ) == 0, NA, PJ))
```

what this is doing is, if the measure is `0` for both `Source`, the sum is 0, and then you replace the value to NA for this group. It eliminates the need for converting the data to wide-format.

Also, possibly look at `mutate_at` to `mutate` multiple columns at the same time.

Comment: That code throws an error. 

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `false` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 2.

Comment: can't debug without data. please edit the question to provide a reproducible example.